# PouchDb not inserting data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

Using ionic framework with angularJS.

I've tried using post and put for pouchdDb, can't get data to post. Anyone have any ideas why I can't post any data?

```
//app.js
var localDB = new PouchDB("myForm", {adapter: 'websql'});
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
//Angular App code here

localDB.post({
    _id: "a5c13f0a-ffe6-ea2b-a6e0-34acd7d1f04b",
    assignment: false,
    creator: "2895b5a1-09b3-4f45-9770-a4d76d82af5f",
    creatorEmail: "email@gmail.com",
    data: {
      "a5c13f0a-ffe6-ea2b-a6e0-34acd7d1f04bd017f920-04ff-241c-2d68-fc9f12cff472": "123",
      "a5c13f0a-ffe6-ea2b-a6e0-34acd7d1f04bd017f920-04ff-241c-2d68-fc9f12cff4721": "123",
      "a5c13f0a-ffe6-ea2b-a6e0-34acd7d1f04bd017f920-04ff-241c-2d68-fc9f12cff4722": "1212"
    },
    formCreatorId: "2895b5a1-09b3-4f45-9770-a4d76d82af5f",
    formId: "f0a31755-86ba-c657-2872-c38d9fb69a00",
    geolocation: ""
  })
```

I look for all docs with the following line:

```
localDB.allDocs().then(function(result){ console.log(result.rows)});
```

I always get a result that doesn't contain any data:

```
{
   "_id": "a5c13f0a-ffe6-ea2b-a6e0-34acd7d1f04b",
   "_rev": "1-2fef768705dff5cff405529442210955",
   "value": {
       "rev": "1-2fef768705dff5cff405529442210955"
   },
   "key": "a5c13f0a-ffe6-ea2b-a6e0-34acd7d1f04b"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allDocs()` method by default does not return the entire document. Instead if just returns the id and current rev. It takes some configuration options, one of them being `include_docs` which can give you the whole doc.

`localDb.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function(result){ console.log(result.rows)});`

This returns the doc and the content as `result.rows[index].doc`.